# WPF ScrollViewer triggering children touch events when panning

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer with some buttons inside which is intended to be used on a touch screen. The problem i have is that when the ScrollViewer is panning/scrolling the buttons within it are firing touchdown events

So in this case i have a listing of say 30 instances of UserBtn and when i scroll through, every time i touch the screen, if i touch a button to initialise the panning, that event will fire when i don't want it to.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening when panning?

```
<ScrollViewer  Name="UserButtonScroll" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" PanningMode="VerticalOnly" PanningRatio="2" ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsManipulationEnabled="True">

                    <ItemsControl Name="UsersButtonControl" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentViewModel.ActiveButtons}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Button Name="UserBtn" Tag="{Binding BtnType}" Style="{Binding Style, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" TouchDown="CommandParse" MaxHeight="150"  BorderThickness="0" Padding="0"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"   Margin="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel Name="ButtonWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: could you switch `Touchdown="CommandParse"` to `Touchup="CommandParse"` instead?. Although not sure this would not create an similar issue when you release a pan on a button....

Comment: @GingerNinja - tried that literally just after posting this, it allows the scroll but the event itself seems to be either really sensitive in that that you need a pixel per pixel accuracy on the button where you place and remove your finger, or its intermittent. I'm guessing the former. Its a bit of a head scratcher!

Comment: what im doing at the minute is switching to `Click=` as the event type and setting `ClickMode="Release"`. This works but the event isnt as "snappy" as touchdown in terms of that it seems subtly slower to relay but its just me that notices at the minute! i'm still on the hunt though for a proper solution

Comment: I typically do everything on a "Click". As i have experiences similar "intermittent" issues. The only other thing i can think of is to do some logic at the Preview Event Level. Although i have usually ended up in a rabbit hole that i have to abandon at some point as there are odd conditions and scenarios that are too complicated to handle

Comment: Yeah thats what i was afraid of, it would get too messy trying to determine whether im panning before allowing a click event to fire etc. its funny though how its always things that should be relatively simple end up taking up so much time!

Answer (score 0):

The way i got around this was to create my own scrollviewer control and override the `OnManipulationDelta` event. With this i could set the threshold of `e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Length` and if greater than a certain value return `base.OnManipulationDelta(e);` otherwise return nothing.

This then seems to delegate the events the way i intend and gives the effect of reducing the sensitivity of the scrollviewer